# How to add CDATA section to SOAPMessage using SAAJ?

Tags: java, cdata, axiom, saaj

I'm trying to add a cdata section to a soap message using saaj (axis2-saaj-1.5.4). I have an xml document which I would like to define as a cdata section and put it into an element inside the body of a soap document... something like the following (although this causes compiler errors):

```
Element cdataElem = doc.createElement("cdata");
CDATASection cdata = doc.createCDATASection(xmlDocAsString);
cdataElem.appendChild(cdata);

SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
soapMessage.getSOAPBody().addChildElement(cdataElem);
```

I can't find a way to do this properly and I'm sure it should be simple... can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using Axis2, why are using SAAJ instead of Axiom?  Axiom is much better.

Comment: the only answer I can give is 'ignorance'... i'll have a look into Axiom

Comment: A bit more detail is that I'm using JAXB to produce an xml document  which then needs to be included in the cdata section of a simple soap document

Comment: SAAJ is the class model used by "standard" Java web services, and it's awful. Axiom is Axis2's proprietary model, and I strongly suggest using that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this using axiom instead of saaj as suggested in by skaffman.

I've used axiom-api-1.2.8.jar and axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar for sample code below:

```
SOAPFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = factory.getDefaultEnvelope();
OMElement xmlElement= factory.createOMElement("search", envelope.getDefaultNamespace());
envelope.getBody().addChild(xmlElement);

OMTextImpl omText = (OMTextImpl) xmlElement.getOMFactory().createOMText(xmlElement, xmlForCdata, XMLStreamConstants.CDATA);
xmlElement.addChild(omText);

System.out.println(envelope.toStringWithConsume());
```

This seems to work very nicely and doesn't convert '<' tags to & lt;

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. Finally I got a solution using saaj:

```
SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();

message.getSOAPBody().addChildElement(message.getSOAPpart().createCDATASection(xmlDocAsString));
```

Apparentetly SOAPPart seems to act as a DOM doc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add a CDATA section with SAAJ by simply surrounding the root element of my XML with a CDATA section and then adding the XML to the element with "element.addTextNode(xmlString)"

As a result the XML entities were not escaped as they are without the CDATA section.

Cheers,
Torsten